# Using external conf folder as resource folder with sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm pretty new to sbt-native-packager. What I want is using external conf folder like a resource folder and configure the files inside it differently on each environment such as production, dev and etc. 
Project has `src/universal/conf` and bunch of configuration files under this directory used by libraries at runtime.

I exclude `src/universal/conf` during build so final jar does not has these conf files as resources. I checked bin/start.sh and only `lib/` folder set as classpath.

How can I accomplish it? What's the best practices? I don't think that `JavaServerPackaging` is more convenient because final jar has several main methods to be used as separate applications on same node. So one dameon application looks like doesn't fit.

Comment: I solve it with a workaround. For others curios about solutions; adding an option file in universal/conf/ includes jvm option paremeters. I added -DlogBack= and -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf and other jvm parameters in this file. Then simply bashConfigFileLocation :=conf/jvmopts was the trick. But still waiting for the better and complete solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few questions with proper solutions for this

- [SBT using sbt-native-packager how to create different build files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900432/709351)
- [What is the recommended way to set JVM options...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32138510/709351)

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.